# SSO for Silverlight 3 and WinForms application

Tags: winforms, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, single-sign-on

I need Single Sign On for two types of application: Silverlight 3 and Windows Forms.

Do you have any advice about how I could implement this?
Windows authentication is one possible solution. Any other?

Thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Is the user authenticating through a Windows domain?  If so you could use the domain credentials from both IIS (assuming that will host web services for Silverlight) and your WinForms.

On the IIS side you would use windows authentication for the web site hosting the Silverlight.

You can get the current user with [WindowsIdentity.GetCurrentUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0.aspx).  From there you can get the username, etc, and map that security context to your application's internal authorization.

The overall idea here is that the single sign-on would occur when the user logged into their workstation, and both the Winforms and IIS (Silverlight) would use that security context.

Comment: Are you thinking about Windows authentication? If yes, that is one possible solution. Any other?

Comment: Well, ya, I thought that it was pretty clear I was talking about Windows authentication ;-).

Comment: What would you do if you were using Forms Authentication?